# Text boot image not pretty one, how do I get pretty one back?

Tags: 10.10, boot, ati, plymouth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boot screen in low graphics/text mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16874/boot-screen-in-low-graphics-text-mode)

When I had 10.04 I messed around with the boot image using a tutorial online to boot with the 800x600 ubuntu boot logo. However after upgrading to 10.10, I now just get "Ubuntu 10.10" in text and no pretty logo.

I reverted my changes (I backed up every file before making the changes), but this hasn't done the trick. :(

1. How do I get the boot logo back
2. How do I get the boot logo in 800x600?

Device:
Dell Studio 15 (i7-720QM 2.8GHz), 1GB ATI Mobility Radeon HD5470 Graphics Card

Driver:
ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your hardware information, specifically your videocard and driver.

Comment: Will add driver info tonight when I get home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't directly related to your issue, but I encountered the text rather than image boot logo a while back. I installed a package called v86d which solved it, the guide below, tells you how to modify Plymouth. Hopefully, it can help you with your issue:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-the-Big-and-Ugly-Plymouth-Logo-in-Ubuntu-10-04-140810.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Having somewhat the same problem, either on 10.04 or 10.10: initial boot was nice, but just after installing proprietary nvidia driver, boot was in text mode!

I've found this page very helpfull:

http://idyllictux.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/lucidubuntu-10-04-high-resolution-plymouth-virtual-terminal-for-atinvidia-cards-with-proprietaryrestricted-driver/

Hope this help.

-- 
didier

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same trouble when i throw in a different resolution than which are natively supported. Esp no 16:9 resolution works. Make it 1280x1024 and it works all good.