# Boot screen in low graphics/text mode

Tags: boot, nvidia, fglrx, plymouth

My ubuntu boot screen shows up in a strange low resolution, almost text mode, instead the usual and sleek white "ubuntu" over dark background. It's not a big issue because when GDM loads everything becomes ok, but If there's an easy way to fix it I would like to give it a try.

Comment: What graphic card and which driver is your machine on?

Comment: @Takkat I'm using a ATI with proprietary driver

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a work around for the problems with proprietary drivers and Plymouth which has worked for me with Nvidia drivers.

1. Install the package [v86d](http://packages.ubuntu.com/v86d) [image: install v86d].
2. Back up and edit the file `/etc/default/grub`:

   ```
   cp /etc/default/grub ~/.etc.default.grub && gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   Replace the line that looks like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` with

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"
   ```

   and the line that looks like `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` with `GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024`.

   In both of these edits, replace `1280x1024` with your desired screen resolution. Make sure you save the file and exit the text editor once you have finished editing.
3. Now edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` just like you did with the previous file:

   ```
   cp /etc/initramfs-tools/modules ~/.etc.initramfs-tools.modules && gksudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
   ```

   Add `uvesafb mode_option=1280x1024-24 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap` to the end of the file then save and close.
4. Now edit the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash` (which may not exist):

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
   ```

   Add this to the file: `FRAMEBUFFER=y`
5. Run `sudo update-grub2` then `sudo update-initramfs -u`.
6. Reboot and feast your eyes on the beauty :)

Comment: Yep, I can confirm that these steps will fix it.  bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/563878  workaround source: http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-the-Big-and-Ugly-Plymouth-Logo-in-Ubuntu-10-04-140810.shtml

Comment: Only now I has the opportunity to test this. Perfect!

Comment: Unfortunately these steps don't work for all resolutions. I can only ever get 2380x1024 working, but not my monitors native resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using the proprietary nvidia or fglrx driver. Install **startupmanager** and try to change the bootloader resolution to one that your monitor supports.

Comment: i used startupmanager to change the bootloader's resolution and, for 1024x768 it worked but it doesn't list my configured monitor's resolution of 1366x768. also, it seems to hang the boot with a blank (black) screen and no disk activity for about 5seconds.

Comment: I have the fglrx driver installed, I'll give it a go with startupmanager later today (not at my desktop righ now) and share the results.

Comment: Here, plymouth splash is fine using radeon driver, no need for fglrx

Comment: with radeon it displays well but fglrx is a much better driver for 3d graphics and hardware acceleration

Comment: I do not think startupmanager has support for widescreen monitors at this moment. Trying playing outwith the options and see what suits you the best.

Comment: Everything's ok now, but thanks for you answer