# Ubuntu 10.10 not normal boot screen

Tags: boot, graphics, ati, display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boot screen in low graphics/text mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16874/boot-screen-in-low-graphics-text-mode)

Hi everyone,

I have installed the latest ATI Drivers from AMD's website and everything's working fine. It's just that with these drivers I get a very simple looking boot screen. It's just a purple screen with "Ubuntu 10.10" written in the center and 3 dots below it.

Is there anyway I can get the default boot screen that everyone see's in Ubuntu 10.10

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this similar post: [Boot screen in low graphics/text mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16874/boot-screen-in-low-graphics-text-mode)

This will help you.