# How to solve the problem booting FGLRX 8.780 + Kernel 2.6.35-25?

Tags: kernel, ati, fglrx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boot screen in low graphics/text mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16874/boot-screen-in-low-graphics-text-mode)

The situation before this all happened is pretty standard. I have a HP Pavillion dv5 laptop with an ATI Mobility Radeon 4200 series. It always worked fine with Ubuntu for as long as I can remember. However, at one point, something happened and truly made a majestic mess of things. It might've been extra repos I enabled with Ubuntu Tweak - I do not know. But something made it so that my system would not boot any longer.

And when I say "won't boot", this is what I mean:
- Durning a normal bootup, any entries (except Windows) selected with GRUB (or BURG, not even sure which one I'm using anymore) will spawn the Ubuntu loading screen - then try to start X (or GDM) 5 times. The screen goes to dark, black and back to the Ubuntu loading screen. Then it just stays there until I spawn another TTY.

I have no idea what is happening or why. There are no errors in my logs, and I'm truly at a loss here.

I've linked three files: Xorg.0.log, the output of dmesg and the GDM log:

- Xorg.0.log: http://ubuntu.pastebin.com/tpVKc2tc
- dmesg: http://ubuntu.pastebin.com/Nd5aYj45
- gdm's :0.log: *couldn't post due to lack of points :(*

Let me know if any of you more knowledgeable folks can restore some sanity in my life. Any help is greatly apreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem on my ATI Technologies Inc RV730XT [Radeon HD 4670]

My solution now is just to use 2.6.35-24 and things work fine.  I have not tried the purge yet.... will come back and update if that works.

Comment: i tried reinstalling fglrx and get the same thing with kernel 2.6.35-25, while things works fine with 2.6.35-24.  I get a segmentation fault when i do startx with 25.

Comment: @pluc Please put a link to the `gdm` log here as a comment. Also let us know if you have been able to solve the problem or not, if you have, then please do answer your question and accept the answer :)

Comment: Also [FGLRX (Catalyst 11.6) is it compatible with kernel 2.6.39](http://askubuntu.com/questions/50687/fglrx-catalyst-11-6-is-it-compatible-with-kernel-2-6-39) provides insight to the asked question.

Answer (score -1):

Try to reinstal fglrx with

```
sudo apt-get purge xorg-driver-fglrx
sudo apt-get install xorg-driver-fglrx
```

Comment: @izx This is an answer, not a comment. It provides explicit instructions for solving the problem. I doubt they would work, but it's still an answer (and it wouldn't be any better as a comment).

Comment: @EliahKagan: I only partially agree--"have you tried this?"-type short "answers" are IMO better put as comments.  (And yes, the auto-comment inserted by review-beta isn't well-phrased).