# FGLRX (Catalyst 11.6) is it compatible with kernel 2.6.39?

Tags: 11.04, kernel, fglrx, ati

I have recently Installed kernel 2.6.39 and also updated the AMD driver to version 11.6, however seems like it's not working. I was hoping that with this new driver AMD had support for the new kernel, but it doesn't.

When I boot using the new kernel I practically get no compositing, and everything is really ugly.

How (if possible) can I patch or else do something about this?

Comment: Kernel 2.6.39-2 fixed any issues i had with FGLRX.

Comment: Is that from xorg-edgers?

Comment: no, i used kernel check to download it and compile it.

Comment: Kay. I got it working as well. I'm going to put the full solution up on ubuntu forums http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10955831#post10955831

Comment: Are you experiencing any memory issue (such as swap being used to 100% and your computer freezing even though it says you have a tonne of ram unused?)

Comment: @ultimatebuster nope

Comment: Strange, I've noticed that issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/51785/swap-shoots-to-100-after-a-couple-of-hours-of-usage Currently using kernelcheck, hopefully that issue is going away.

Comment: What the hell happened?.. Anyhow I used kernel check to install the kernel again. And also, is it possible for you to pose your `free -m` output somewhere? There's a huge kernel leak somewhere... i think..

Comment: @ultimatebuster, sorry  for that :O , here's the free -m http://pastebin.com/imG3PLRi, i did had my pc freeze, now that i remember,  but that was because of compiz which i downgraded and now is fine.

Comment: Weird.. Is your uname -a something similar to this: `Linux ulti-laptop 2.6.39.3-candela #1 SMP Sat Jul 16 12:55:43 CST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
`

Comment: Yes it is ,`Linux uri-MS-7267 2.6.39.3-candela #1 SMP Wed Jul 13 00:10:24 CDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a blog entry [here](http://henryhermawan.blogspot.com/2011/06/ati-catalyst-proprietary-display-driver.html) which states that you have to patch the new catalyst driver to make it work with 2.6.39

Full instructions can be found in that blog together with links to the source code which need to be used to patch.

EDIT: Since the original question was for Catalyst 11.5, the question has been revised for Catalyst 11.6

[This forum entry](http://forum.xbmc.org/showpost.php?p=818779&postcount=117) gives instructions on how to compile the patches for this new catalyst version - To complete the answer, I've reproduced the answer - note - this is for 64bit - if you are using 32bit, you'll need to change the entries for "x86_64" for the 32bit equivalents.  Also you will not need to install the ia32-libs library:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
sudo apt-get install -y ia32-libs
cd ~; mkdir catalyst11.6; cd catalyst11.6
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-11-6-x86.x86_64.run
wget http://www.mindwerks.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/2.6.39_bkl.patch
wget http://www.mindwerks.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/no_bkl.patch
chmod +x ati-driver-installer-11-6-x86.x86_64.run
sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-6-x86.x86_64.run --extract ati
cd ati; for i in ../*.patch; do patch -p1 < $i; done
./ati-installer.sh 8.861 --buildpkg Ubuntu/natty
cd ..
rm -rf ati
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I applied the patch and afterwards it said there was an error when building the kernel module.

Comment: yeah... still don't have any compositing

Comment: I noticed that you changed the question from v11.5 to 11.6.  The blog entry made clear that it was tested only to 11.5.  Any reason why you cant use that tested version?

Comment: beacause on 11.5 i'm unable to apply the overscan settings for my tv, so i downloaded 11.6 shortly after i made this question, and installed it, but i still didn't have any compositing.