# Ubuntu 12.04 Running Faster Than Normal

Tags: 12.04

I have just installed a new copy of Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop . i have noticed that my system is running **4x to 5x faster than normal** . i have just install Vmware Desktop & centos for testing something . i have noticed that i has installed in just like less than 1 minute !!

My system is booting so fast that after starting my laptop i got GUI in like 10 to 13 sec & shutting down in like 2 to 3 sec & all programs ( Firefox , Chrome , etc ) running so fast that i can see ....

The only change i made after installation is

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness 
1
```

[How do I configure swappiness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness)

The System is **Dell N 5110 i7** with **8GB** of RAM

#### **So my question is that what should i look for that why my system running very fast ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article you linked to and the contents of your post, it looks like your swappiness is 1, and that seems to mean that your system will prefer to use your ram more often than to save things to your disk. So the answer to your question is that you have low swappiness and lots of ram. I definitely could be wrong on this, but based on the link you posted that seems to be what is happening.

Comment: my swappiness on all my system is 10 .. i did 1 this time ... all are working normal .... i got a desktop & 2 laptops ....

Comment: i had ubuntu before swappiness was 10 on this laptop ... working normal ...so to me its not that .. i think

Comment: Well if your swappiness was 10 before and its 1 now then it would be faster. It could also be that 12.04 is faster than the versions your were used to before. Add that with lower swappiness and that could explain it.