# Why dont changes to the swappiness remain permanent after reboot?

Tags: swap

System Ubuntu 14.04

I want to change my swappiness from the default 60 to 10. According to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/103916/71679 I need to log in as root and edit `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` and add or edit to `vm.swappiness = 10`

When opening that file as root I only see the number 60 when I add `vm.swappiness = 10`and try to save I get  Error writing /proc/sys/vm/swappiness: Invalid argument

If I simply change 60 to 10 the file saves without issue I check the changes take place with `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` it shows the changes took place

By editing this file as root I was under the assumption the changes would remain permanent but once I shut down and restart the default is back to 60. Why aren't the changes remaining permanent? What writes the file back to 60 after reboot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I configure swappiness?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to set the `swapiness` without rebooting you could execute the following command:

```
echo 10 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

This will set the `swapiness` to 10 in this case. You can only echo a number because all this will do is call a kernel function to set the `swapiness` to 10 and this function only accepts numbers (this explains why you get a invalid argument error: you're trying to write other characters than numbers).

However, this is only temporary. The value will be reset at the next reboot to the default value.

To make the change permanent:

1. Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` as root

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
   ```
2. Add the following line to the file:

   ```
   vm.swappiness = 10
   ```
3. Save the file using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

The changes made to `sysctl.conf` will apply on reboot or you can reload them using `sudo sysctl -p` (so `sudo sysctl -p` will have the same effect as `echo 10 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` in this case).

Comment: Fastest response time ever :) i will try it out and report back.......thanks!

Comment: and to check it `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`

Answer (score 0):

You can straight up do the steps below for permanent settings:

1. `vi /etc/sysctl.conf`
2. Add `vm.swappiness=10`
3. `:x`
4. `sysctl -p`

And for temporary do:

1. `echo 10 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`

PS: *This wont persist after reboot*