# How to permanently change swappiness

Tags: lubuntu, swap

I am trying to **permanently** change my swappiness level,i’ve seen an answer posted in a few places and everyone being greateful, saying it works. But it isn’t for me…

This is the question/answer i looked at:

[Why dont changes to the swappiness remain permanent after reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463281/why-dont-changes-to-the-swappiness-remain-permanent-after-reboot)

But after entering:
`sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`

i get a list come up saying various things all with a hashtags in front of each line….

Where exactly do i add `vm.swappiness=10`??
do i add a hashtag in front of it too like everything else in the file?
I added it to the very top of the file and saved, rebooted, hasnt changed anything.
I also added it to the bottom and saved, rebooted…..still hasn’t changed. my swappiness is still 60.

Could someone please be a bit more specific with this please? I'm far from an expert when it comes to linux

Thanks

Comment: [The answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/463283/20054) is very clear. Just copy/paste the line from there. Also, does it have a hash tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add that at the bottom without the `#` before it then run:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Sample from my `sysctl.conf` file:

```
# Log Martian Packets
#net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1
#
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
#vm.swappiness=0
fs.file-max = 2097152
vm.overcommit_memory=1
net.core.somaxconn=65536
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=8192
```