# New 14.04 LTS Install Extremely Slow Overall

Tags: 14.04

I am new to Ubuntu.  I have a DINOSAUR machine that was not being used, and thought it would be a learning experience to wipe it clean and try a Linux-based OS.

14.04 LTS was installed on a completely clean hard drive (DoD wipe specifications).  Ubuntu OS boots just fine, but ALL operations are extremely slow to react to user inputs.

Computer specs:

- 14.04 LTS 32-bit OS;
- 512MB (495.2 MiB reporting) PC2700 DDR 333MHz RAM;
- Intel® Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.40GHz;
- VGA Video: Radeon 9000
- Series R200 (RV250 4966) x86/MMX/SSE2 TCL DRI2;
- 60 GB Hard Drive (58.4 GB reporting);
- 8PE667U Gigabyte Motherboard, BIOS: Award v6 Oct2002

Thus far, only diagnostic action was to generate 'system.html' with a report of all  components.  Some of the blocks are highlighted in red, but I am not experienced enough to interpret the results and take corrective action.  Is there a way to share the file with this community to help expedite a potential solution?

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/493189/why-is-ubuntu-14-04-so-slow-on-my-laptop/493192#493192) answer should help - they were in a similar position for you, and I think your problem is your lack of RAM.

Comment: With very old systems like hte ones you've stated, you may want to consider using a lighter variant of Ubuntu.  Try Lubuntu, as is stated in that question linked.

Comment: I will report back if 14.04 speeds up with a 1 GB RAM upgrade. My thanks to both Tim and Thomas W.

Comment: USE XUBUNTU and review the tips and tricks I answered below..should help a ton!  Disable effects in CCSM TOO!

Answer (score 0):

Yup your Ram is the problem consider adding AT LEAST another 512mb...here are some other tips to speed things up!  Since you have such little Ram I HIGHLY RECOMMEND USING **XUBUNTU**!

1. Change Swap
   gksudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf

ADD THIS ENTRY AT END AND SAVE

vm.swappiness=5

Remove bloatware
https://fixubuntu.com/

wget -q -O - https://fixubuntu.com/fixubuntu.sh | bash

Get the following Tweak Tools
Ubuntu Tweak ( sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak )

Tweak Tool ( sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool )

Unity Tweak ( sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool )

Dconf Editor ( sudo apt-get install dconf-tools )

Compiz Config Editor ( sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra -y )

Review each section of each tool and modify as desired

Get Bleachbit
I suggest downloading the newest version as the one in the repository(Software Center) is old. You can download it here: http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/download/linux

Review the following sites and modify your system as needed.
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/first#TOC-Decrease-the-swap-use-very-important-

https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/speed

http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-software-linux.htm?page=0,0#Introduction

http://smashingweb.info/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-lts-for-perfect-desktop/

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=140920

http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/tips-and-tricks-ubuntu-after-installation-ubuntu-1404.htm

Check FPS

Open terminal

type glxgears

hit enter

HOPE THIS INFO HELPS A BIT!

**One other awesome tool I use is CPU Indicator**

Open Terminal

Install

sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq

Run

'indicator-cpufreq' in terminal to launch

**Reboot!!! You will see the icon in the top bar of unity interface.
Right or left click icon and select the fastest cpu speed or desired speed! This tool is AWESOME and will help a TON!**