# ubuntu 14.04 is slow @ 12gb Ram

Tags: 14.04, configuration, ram

Recently I was upgrade my ubuntu to 14.04 ,after that for any event(copying a file or running any application)it is only consuming 3gb of memory only .

it is not able to use my entire Ram .Due to this some times i feel system slowness as well .

my system config :

```
i5 processor 
12gb ram
1 tb hard disk (but I don't have any swap partition )
```

It would be really great if any one can tell me how to use 12 GB of RAM in a efficient way.

Comment: This is not enough information to go on. I would suggest to at least include `uname` and some statistics regarding `free` or `top`

Comment: It is possible you installed the 32 bit version of Ubuntu. 32 Bit Ubuntu would be limited to about 3GB of ram.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you installed the 32-bit version of Ubuntu. To check, open up a termianl and type `uname -p`. That will tell you if you have 32-bit (in which you'll get iX86, where X can be anything) or x86_64, 64-bit. You should have 64-bit. If not, it's time to back up and [reinstall](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Also, you have 12GB of RAM, which is quite a bit. I think that you should set your swappiness to 3. For information on how to do this, read the first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness). Now, if you do have 32-bit Ubuntu, change the swappiness after you install 64-bit Ubuntu, as it will benefit you greatly. Use a task management tool like GNOME System Monitor (preinstalled with Ubuntu) to check your processor use. Maybe it's your processor that's slow. P.S. If you have a solid-state drive, set your swappiness to 0. If you have a solid-state drive, you NEVER EVER EVER want to make or use swap on it. If you have an SSD, I suggest deleting that swap right now.