# is this best partition for ubuntu server?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, raid

I have 250gb ssd, 6x 3tb hdd and 16gb memory.

I partitioned ssd;

16gb swap, 30gb /, rest of /home

raid 6 for hdd and no spare, no swap just ext4 /home

I will use this server for store all my media and files also backup.

I would like to know if this setup is good and if there is better setup please advise me

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would advise making the following changes:

## Use your SSD for the OS

---

You have ***tons*** of hard drive space with your HDDs. Therefore, I would use the entire SSD for your `/` partition.

Also, I would move your swapdrive off of the SSD because, well, [SSDs aren't the best for swapping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652337/why-no-swap-partitions-on-ssd-drives).

Similarly, I would move your `/tmp` folder off of the SSD.

## Set Up LVM

---

You have six hard drives available. Set up a LVM system spanning the six full HDDs. This will act similar to a RAID, but will offer you slightly better performance and will allow you to define more partitions faster. All in all, LVM is a Good Thing™.

If you want to use a RAID-like striping setup, there are [ways to do that](http://linuxdocs.org/HOWTOs/LVM-HOWTO-8.html), but they're not the simplest. However, I'm guessing that you're using RAID as a form of backup. This is a very *very **very*** bad idea. RAID has never been and will never be a replacement to backing up.

On your LVM system, I would create a 16GB swap partition. From there, assign another 100GB to `/tmp` so you can have a reliable tempdriver without murdering your SSD. Send the rest to your `/home` partition, or even better, a specific partition for storing files (maybe `/files`?).

Comment: I couldn't agree more about the swap, I would go further and recommend that you never allow any thing that completes a lot of writes to the disk to use an SSD.