# Swap on SSD - will it decrease life sizeably?

Tags: ssd, swap

I have a samsung 850 evo 120GB ssd. I have installed ubuntu on it , with a 119GB / and 1 GiB Swap(on the ssd) . Is the swap a good idea? Should I remove the swap ? Problem is , I have only 1 GB ram.

EDIT - My question is not about *where* to put the swap , it's about how putting swap on the ssd affects its lifespan significantly.

Comment: That very much depends on how much you use the swap. See also [Why no swap partitions on SSD drives?](http://askubuntu.com/q/652337)

Comment: @JonasCz my swappiness is 60

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not swap on ssd to avoid reduction of the life cycle, but I also have 16 GB RAM. 
Depending on your system ram is very cheap (8gb ddr3 30€). This would be the only good solution. 
You can try to turn off swapping, but this can decrease the performance of your system. You can install lubuntu-desktop and switch to lxde to safe ram