# How to optimize SSD in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, ssd, tweak, optimization

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 on my SSD(Adata Su650 240GB). I wanted to know if there are any tweaks that are needed to be done for the SSD to work properly and increase its lifespan.

Note:- During installation I didn't create any Swap partition.

Answer (score 1):

There should not be any tools needed to be activated as they already will be when installing the system. [fstrim](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fstrim.8.html) is that tool but if your ssd is not supported you can not use it anyways.

```
journalctl -u fstrim
```

will show the status.

```
systemctl list-timers --all
```

will show the active timers (so will also show fstrim).

```
sudo systemctl start fstrim.timer
```

to active it if it is disabled. It will do nothing though if your ssd is unsupported.

```
 lsblk --discard
```

to check for support. Check the values of DISC-GRAN (discard granularity) and DISC-MAX (discard max bytes) columns. Non-zero values indicate TRIM support.

And we do not use a swap partition anymore. We use a swapfile. See `more /etc/fstab`. It will show how swap is created on your system. Here you can also check for fstrim support: the line that mounts your ssd will have a setting `errors=` with the option `discard`.

Comment: Will swap file reduce my ssd's lifespan? If so then how can I disable it permanantely?

Comment: Trim already takes care of limiting writes as much as possible and you do not want to use Linux without a swap. Please read https://askubuntu.com/questions/652337/why-no-swap-partitions-on-ssd-drives

Comment: If you have a HDD alongside the SSD you could put swap on the HDD but i would not be worried about the reducing of lifespan on an ssd. You are more likely to buy a new system before the end of the life of the ssd is up ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind thank God... there's somebody else on the planet who thinks that "you do not want to use Linux without a swap" :-) Bravo!

Comment: executing this command 'sudo systemctl start fstrim.timer'  gives me  'Failed to start fstrim.timer: Unit fstrim.timer not found.' what do I do now?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu (is it one that uses systemd?)  also check that the ssd is in ext format. next check if the ssd is supported for fstrim (if any of these test fails the service is likely not installed ;) )

Comment: Its ubuntu 16.04. The ssd is in ext4 format and yes my ssd has trim support