# swap- do I need to delete it on ssd

Tags: ssd, swap, secure-erase

Respected admin,
I am a proud linux user since last 5 years. My notebook configuration is core i5 with 12gb ddr3,120 gb ssd, 640gb hdd. Now when I have shifted on ssd I simply made default install of ubuntu, in which out of 120 99gb is made to system drive and 12 is made swap. On my CPU usage of about 70-80% my Max ram usage majority times is about 50% Max. approx.Now I wanted to know that does that swap is even used in moderate-heavy usage, and is there any point in removing it, and if yes,then how-to.

Comment: I like to have it, but if you are 100% positive you will never hit max RAM, you don’t need it. Personally, even though I have lots if RAM, I use it to be safe and because it can speed things up even if you’re not maxing out RAM

Comment: Default install of Ubuntu?  without any details as to which product (Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Desktop?) nor any release details. You've provided a *vague* question seeking opinions (*off-topic on this site - see https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask as better suited to [forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/) & not a Q&A site like this*) without required specifics of product/release, nor how the machine will be used that influence the question. To me the question is unclear & off-topic sorry.

Comment: Since many release ago the default Ubuntu installation has a swapfile instead of a swap partition. So either you're using a very old and unsupported release or you didn't do a default installation. And for the record, this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1294164/1210606 from the suggested Q&A reflects the experience most users have, so you don't have to worry about. The actual default installation creates a dynamic swapfile up to 2GB (can be increased) that works for 90%+ of the usage scenarios.

Comment: TLDR; swap increases performance under moderate to heavy use, particularly when using a SSD. If you don't have any performance issues, I would leave it as is.

Comment: What does `free -m` show both when first booted & when using a lot of apps? Typically a desktop user will not use swap if you have a lot of RAM unless editing videos or very large photos. And since not using swap, not an issue. And now SSDs have similar life to HDDs anyway.