# Why server uses swap

Tags: swap

My server has 64GB total RAM and currently the server has 13GB free. But, it takes the swap. What will be the reason?

The server using numactl.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly explained, RAM is used by two things:

- Loaded programs
- Harddisk cache to speed-up read- and write-access

If a program is started but doesn't use some parts of its allocated RAM, it will be swapped to disk to make space for harddisk cache to improve harddisk performance.

The aggressiveness of swapping out programs is called swappiness. You can find is a more in-depth [explanation here](https://askubuntu.com/a/103916/75166) on how to configure it.