# Why is that much memory used while I only have a terminal window open?

Tags: kubuntu, ram, memory-usage

I just installed Kubuntu 15.04, installed VLC, Chrome and configured some settings then ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` to upgrade the system and [noticed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjVTC.png) that 2.6 GB of ram is being used! (and 3.4 GB while running Chrome).

Is that normal for the system? will it slow it down when doing more heavy multitasking? why isn't it using any swap to lower the load on the memory?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `free` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

USE:

`sudo top`

and then hit Shift+m (i.e. write a capital M) to order it by MAX usage.

This will give you an idea what eats up your RAM....then we can try to examine this further

- Also increased memory usage when running Chrome is completely normal, because Chrome is known to be memory glutton...
- Maybe your OS isn't using SWAP just because it doesn't need to, or your [swapiness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness) is set to be low...
- KDE e.g. Kubuntu isn't among the most lightweight Ubuntu flavours (it may eat up more RAM than other flavours)

Comment: To add to the above, I find htop to be a nicer interface. It is basically the same thing as top in functionality and a little nicer to look at. You can download this with `sudo apt-get install htop` and then just run `htop` from the terminal - htop supports input from the mouse as well. It should be in the standard repositories - you can check with `sudo apt-cache search htop` to see if it's listed. It should be there by default.