# Booting Windows 10 after Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I'm currently using the latest version on Ubuntu. It's great but I would like to use windows 10 as there are many more games and aplications running on that operating system. Is there any way i can dual boot or get windows without loosing all of my data.

I'm new to computer stuff as i have only just built mine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn't this is my own question.

Comment: I have Ubuntu installed already not windows.

Comment: @OwainWilliams the «possible duplicate» means that your question seems was already asked by someone else, and answered.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu

Comment: @OwainWilliams In addition to Hi-Angel's comment: ... and that you should edit your question and explaining why the possible duplicate isn't one.

Comment: @OwainWilliams also — it might be obvious, but you said you're new, so… — note that you can still launch Windows apps with *WINE* *(you can even want to find the latest PPA with it)*. Also, if you have NVidia, for gaming stuff you would better installing proprietary drivers. With Radeon, the FOSS ones often works better. Also one of the things I do with the fresh Ubuntu — is [decreasing swappiness to ≈10%](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness).

Comment: Is computer hardware newer UEFI or older BIOS? How you install is greatly different. And is Ubuntu installed in UEFI or BIOS/CSM mode if hardware is UEFI? Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to *install Ubuntu after installing Windows* as Windows is notorious for not liking dual boots, whereas Ubuntu *likes* dual boots.

If you can't do it in that order (E.G. by backing up all your data):

1. Back-up all your data anyway just in case anything goes wrong.
2. Download and burn a [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) DVD.
3. Shrink your Ubuntu Install to have enough space for Windows
4. Move the Ubuntu install off the first partition (Windows insists on being installed on partition 1)
5. Install Windows
6. Turn off Windows FastBoot and Hibernation
7. Run the Boot repair as Windows *will have overwritten* your boot record during its install process