# Is there a way to make SWAP partition really like memory for demanding program?

Tags: ram, swap

My Thinkpad T61 can only have 4GB RAM, but a program requires at least 4GB memory. I have allocated 16GB swap partition.

When the program starts, it complaints

```
Insufficient memory allocation. Required is 4000000 KB, but configured is 3979756 KB.
```

Is there a way to make the O/S consider the swap partition more like real RAM?

Comment: Even if you could, it would work unbearably slow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. It doesn’t work exactly as RAM does, but it may help you a lot. There’s a parameter called swapiness. This is the measure of how frequently to use your swap space. A higher value means higher access rates.
More about setting swappiness can be found on the question [How do I configure swappiness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness)

I think you need a higher swappiness rate. But it would be better to add more memory than to increase your swappiness, as this can cause problems for your hard disk drive.