# Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 hanging on full memory as swapping starts to happen (swapoff prevents the problem). What to do?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, ram, freeze, swap

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 without any issues for more than a week. Due to a subsequent update most probably, running memory-intensive tasks causes the system to hang completely (image freezes, no response to mouse and keyboard input including Ctrl+Alt+F*, SSH server stops responding). I've only waited a few minutes at a time once this happened before powering off.

Tried switching to a previous kernel version (4.10.19 instead of 4.10.21), but the issue still occurred.

My SSD seems fine (SMART tests, `fsck`, and `badblocks` report no problems on all partitions). Windows boots normally and swaps OK. Couldn't find anything in `syslog` (I don't think logging still works when this happens).

My only solution right now is to stop swapping and start losing processes when my memory usage hits maximum.

What are my options here? Is there a way to identify which update is causing this issue? If I wait long enough will (and if so how long?) would the system become responsive again?

I do not remember installing any packages before this started to happen, which is why I'm thinking this was caused by an update.

### Update:

As I was using my computer without swap to avoid it hanging I've noticed the following:

I reactivated swap and set swappiness to 80% and then to 100%, and even though my RAM usage was above 60%, not swapping happened in either case.

This means that swap is not working. I've also tried to use a different swap area which didn't help.

Comment: Try [reducing your swappiness](https://askubuntu.com/a/103916/595510).

Comment: Thanks @MarkYisri. I've actually noticed that the system was using about 190Mb of swap the last time it froze, and the RAM was increasing steadily until it hit the maximum and the system stopped responding. This is why I think the problem is with aggressive swapping as the main memory saturates. My instinct is to increase the swappiness so that the system would not have to wait until RAM is full and be forced to shove a whole lot of data in the swap partition because there's nowhere else to put it. I'll experiment with both I guess and I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: **Don't run badblocks on a SSD!** From the `terminal` show me the output of `free -h` and `swapon` and `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`. Set your vm.swappiness back to 60. Edit/paste that output into your question, not the comments, please. Start comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @Anthony how much RAM do you have?

Comment: Same problem here, except I use 16.04 LTS. The issue gets worse when I use kernel 4.11, but it also occurs (freezes, but sometimes unfreezes) on 4.4. Played with swapiness and other parameters, but nothing helps. I think the problem is in the custom Ubuntu kernel.