# Ubuntu 17.04 slow boot on SSD with dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, swap

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.04 on dual boot (120Gb SSD, 100 for windows and the rest for Linux).
When I installed Ubuntu in the second partition, I did not create any swap partition (I have 4Gb of ram and most forums said that with 4Gb+ you do not need swap), so I just created a root partition `/` with all the 20gb available and selected to encrypt my Home folder only.

The thing is that it's taking 1-2min to boot Ubuntu, while windows boots up in around 10 seconds or less.

I saw some posts here about this issue but most of the cases the OP had the swap partition created, and this is not my case.

What can I do? Install it again and create a swap partition this time or do I take another approach? I'm not tech savvy regarding Ubuntu, so I'd appreciate if you guys show me some steps do identify the issue, thanks!

**EDIT #1**

My Windows 10 is not set with fastboot because I can access all files/folders of Windows partition inside Linux.

**EDIT #2**

Output from `sudo fdisk -l` :

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 80,5 MiB, 84393984 bytes, 164832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 76 MiB, 79683584 bytes, 155632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 111,8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x39380a4e

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048   1026047   1024000  500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1026048 193478655 192452608 91,8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       193480702 234440703  40960002 19,5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       193480704 234440703  40960000 19,5G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 931,5 GiB, 1000204138496 bytes, 1953523708 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2de2a99a

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 1953519615 1953517568 931,5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Output from `systemd-analyze` :

```
Startup finished in 5.074s (kernel) + 3min 514ms (userspace) = 3min 5.588s
```

Output from `systemd-analyze blame` :

```
7.518s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
3.920s fwupd.service
3.015s iio-sensor-proxy.service
1.217s dev-sda5.device
739ms apt-daily.service
```

**EDIT #3:**

Output from `systemd-analyze critical-chain` :

```
graphical.target @1min 38.007s
└─multi-user.target @1min 38.007s
  └─virtualbox.service @1min 37.938s +68ms
    └─network-online.target @1min 37.937s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 30.418s +7.518s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 30.306s +105ms
          └─dbus.service @1min 30.281s
            └─basic.target @1min 30.273s
              └─sockets.target @1min 30.273s
                └─snapd.socket @1min 30.265s +8ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 30.264s
                    └─apparmor.service @193ms +264ms
                      └─local-fs.target @190ms
                        └─media-gdf897g6f9-HD\x20TOURO.mount @1min 50.061s
                          └─dev-sdb1.device @1.467s
```

**EDIT #4:**

Here's a image of command `systemd-analyze plot > test.svg`, a huge gap before **sysinit.target**, not sure what it means.

http://svgur.com/s/2SA

Comment: Indeed, with enough RAM swap is hardly used and since 17.04 it uses a swap file instead of the traditional partition therefore your partitioning is correct. No, Windows doesn't boot so fast. It actually never shuts down by default (fast startup feature that should be disabled for dual boot anyway).

Comment: You need swap, but that won't fix a slow boot situtation. First thing I'd check is if you have the most current BIOS, and the most current firmware for your SSD. Then I'd check for partition misalignment... edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo fdisk -l`. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: added the output @heynnema

Comment: Looks normal. Lets check syslog... `grep -i -e sda -e ata1 /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: @heynnema too long to post here, so here it is -- https://pastebin.com/drqwRex0

Comment: Did you only post about a dozen lines? If so, there's no problem there. Did you check for an updated BIOS or SSD firmware?

Comment: @heynnema also updated my question with couple more outputs to help the diagnostics, but regarding the SSD and BIOS I have no idea how to check that, but at least I have a starting point to research, thanks for the support bro :)

Comment: For the BIOS you enter your BIOS at boot time, using the key shown on the splash screen, probably F2/ESC/DEL or some such, then note the BIOS version number. Then go to the manufacturer's web site with the make/model # of the computer, and go to the support section/downloads and look for an updated BIOS download. SSD same idea, take the make/model# and go to the manufactuer's web site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find a fix that a Reddit user posted, it was actually a bug:

> In Ubuntu 17.04, there is a bug in the installer when using home
>   folder encryption - a swap partition is referenced but 17.04 now uses
>   a swap file.
>
> Open /etc/crypttab in a text editor and change the following:
>
> cryptswap1 UID=XXXXXXXX
>
> to this:
>
> cryptswap1 /swapfile

Now my Ubuntu boots in like 6 seconds :-)

Comment: 17.10, can`t find this file in /etc/

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 takes less time, because by default it doesn't shutdown completely (If you want to access your windows partition from Linux, you have to turn off this feature). It hibernates and resumes at power on. Creating swap partition is a good thing as some apps use swap area (like gimp, inkscape, vmware etc). you can control swapiness for your OS, that will help you reduce the wear-tear of your SSD.

**Use following link to adjust swapiness**

[How do I configure swappiness?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness)

**And to add swap to your install use**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Or you can start from fresh install.

And if you know exactly what kind of hardware you have, you can disable unwanted modules from kernel.

Keep only wanted apps in startup applications.

Disable services to start on, such as

- ftp server
- apache or nginx
- clamav
- openssh-server

etc.

But then you have to start them manually or you can add crontabs to start them after bootup.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, with exactly 30 seconds gap around the following entries on dmesg, which reduced to less than 1 second after the fix -

> ```
> [    3.675210] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
> [    3.804315] [drm] RC6 on
> [    4.566877] random: crng init done
> [    4.566879] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
> ```

I tried several fixes suggested, without any success -

1. Updating '`/etc/fstab`' with output from '`blkid`'
2. Installing haveged and rng-tools or rng-tools5 (although my processor has support for Secure Key)

It turns out that the issue was that initramfs tried to locate the swap space that I had created while installing from a live USB. The UUID of swap partition lying on the USB is sought for 30 seconds, before moving on with the boot. This needs to be fixed at two places -

1. `update-initramfs -uk all`' #using updated version of initramfs-tools - 0.130ubuntu3.1
2. Removing the override (if any) from '`/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`' by either commenting out the entry or marking `RESUME=none`

Detailed bug fix given here - 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1771962