# How do I reduce my boot time on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boot, 18.04

Since I have upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 my boot time has increased tremendously. I cannot understand the problem after looking at my dmesg. Please help me to find the exact problem. [dmesg](https://pastebin.com/D7PgzbQP) 
Edit : [systemd-analyze blame](https://pastebin.com/tj2Bqfiy)

Comment: When booting, in the GRUB menu, press `e`, and delete the options `quiet splash`, then press `f10`. You will see the full loading of the kernel. Check out where does the system slow down.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `systemd-analyze blame` (the first 20 or so lines are relevant).

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018907/ubuntu-installation-stuck-at-random-crng-init-done, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442698/when-i-log-in-it-hangs-until-crng-init-done. I've noticed you have kernel 5.1. How are boot times with an official Ubuntu kernel from the repositories?

Answer (score 0):

Read the lines 176 - 179 of your dmesg carefully. As to be seen in line 218
you have radeon-graphics and can delete 'nomodeset' out of grub securely.-watnu