# Ubuntu 20.04: boot hungs after "random: fast/crng init done"

Tags: boot, 20.04

First ran into this problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 in an old HP Pavillion laptop (dv7-2185dx): the system was stuck at a blank screen *sometimes* after a boot/reboot. After editing grub to enable debug mode (`linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0.58-generic root=... ro debug`), I see that whenever the boot sequence hangs, it is always after "random: fast init done" or `random: crng init done` (or both). Sample output below:

[snapshot: boot halts after crng init done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azg5b.jpg)

I have checked previous questions on similar issues, e.g.:
[Ubuntu installation stuck at random crng init done](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018907/ubuntu-installation-stuck-at-random-crng-init-done)
[Boot - very slow start "random: fast init done"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118953/boot-very-slow-start-random-fast-init-done)

However, the solutions there don't work in my case: I have no SD cards to remove, I boot from an internal SSD and my UUIDs in `blkid` and `fstab` agree, my system does not use a swap partition but rather a swap file in the same partition as the system, I tried installing `rng-tools` and `haveged` but the situation was not resolved. I also did a fresh 20.04 installation and this problem occurred there too.

Curiously, I have Ubuntu 18.04 in another partition of the same disk which always boots fine. Both systems seem to use the same `initrd` image version (`initrd.img-5.4.0-58-generic`).

I am baffled at this point, hence the request for help. The problem is not even well-reproducible, it happens *randomly* but quite frequently. Any ideas what might be going on, or at least any pointers on how to troubleshoot?

Happy to provide more info as necessary...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently.
The boot process was sometimes stuck on:

> random: fast init done

After a while it got stuck on:

> random: crng init done

According to post #8 in [this forum](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/debian-hangs-at-boot-with-random-crng-init-done-4175613405/):

> At boot, the kernel waits for mouse movements to initialize the random number generator.

Being a headless server, I don't have anything attached to it. And, indeed, if I simply attach a keyboard, after some test-reboots, the problem never occurs.

After some searching around, I found out that [the linux kernel relies on several inputs (including user inputs) for random number generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing)).

So, in this case, for some reason, it just hangs there, waiting for some kind of "input".

**The solution is to install [havaged](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Haveged)** (Hardware Volatile Entropy Gathering and Expansion):

```
sudo apt install haveged
sudo systemctl enable haveged
```