# I have about 300 gigs of unallocated space. How do I allocate it to Linux?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

[image: confusing :(]

I saw some tutorials that state I need to delete linux-swap? I don't seem to have that :(

Comment: In fact you don't have a swap partition at all. If your release is 17.04, may be it's using swapiness (https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness).

Comment: @Redbob do you mean a swap file?

Comment: I don't know why a tutorial on allocating unallocated space would tell you to *delete* your swap partition, but if you don't have one then you certainly don't need to delete it. What exactly are you trying to do? Please [edit] your question to explain your goal more specifically and what you need help with, if the linked post (which is very general) doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

The unallocated space is before the linux partition. You can not extend a partition from its beginning but only its end. You need to move the partition to the beginning of the unallocated space and then extend.

Moreover, the partition you need to move is the root partition of the system. You cannot move it while you are booted to it. So you need to boot a live system on another drive and run gparted from there.