# Why is swap being used when vm.swappiness is 0?

Tags: swap

To try and fix an issue, I set swappiness to as low as possible, a 0, and swap is still being used. Why?

Running `free -m` gives:

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            484         241           8          58         235         134
Swap:          1023          97         926
```

Comment: Maybe because RAM is *full*? Or you had set it incorrectly? Add more detail like how exactly you configured it and the output of `free -m`

Comment: You've got a pretty small amount of memory for Ubuntu in this machine - what version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: It's a VPS on Ubuntu 16.04(I can't afford a better server now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swappiness defines when swap is used.

For instance, swappiness of 40 defines to begin using swap when there is 40% of RAM left to use.

Swappiness of 0 defines swap is used when the RAM is full and 0% left to use.

To disable swap (totally not recommended as you could possibly end up with an unusable system), you run:

`sudo swapoff -a`

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/103915/367990

Comment: [`swappiness` is a bit more complex than what memory usage swap begins to be used at](https://lwn.net/Articles/83588/).