# Is there any way I can prevent Ubuntu 16 from freezing under heavy CPU load?

Tags: unity, java, performance

I'm a developer working a lot with Android Studio. When it compiles the Java classes it spins up 4+ threads of CPU intensive work. Often I play music in the background when that goes on. Here's what happens:

- The music skips or completely stops at the most intensive section of the compilation
- The mouse point jitters or stops responding altogether

Most often things normalize after compilation is done, but other times the computer freezes totally and I have to hard reset it. How come? Is not Linux/Ubuntu/Unity designed to prioritize the UI thread? How does it allow Java to take 100% of the CPU resources? Is there any way I can throttle this?

Disclaimer: I don't know much about OS code.

Comment: you can use cpulimit to restrict cpu hungry process http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2014/11/04/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linux kernel is really good at managing the CPU, so I think your problem is IO related. It is totally normal that the CPU is used 100% when you're compiling, and this is what you've paid for.

However, I agree with you, the UI should not be so badly affected.

**About your unresponsiveness of your system**

I think you should try [`ionice`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/ionice.1.html) to lower the IO priority of android studio.

**Memory**

It's also possible that your system is low on RAM, and start using swap. `top` can be used to see the swap usage. This can be fixed either by reducing RAM usage, by adding RAM or eventually tuning the [swappiness](https://askubuntu.com/a/103916/454520) of your system.

Unfortunately, I'm not a user of Android Studio, and I can't help with it's configuration.

**About the complete freeze**

This should really not happen, this is a bug and you should fill a bug on the [ubuntu bugtracker](http://launchpad.net/).

But before filling a bug, I think you should update your system, including installing the latest HWE kernel and Xorg (see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)).

Comment: More research leads me to believe it's memory-related. Process kswapd0 hogs CPU when I notice jittering. No easy solution for that I guess (except download more RAM). I'm accepting your answer as it adresses CPU congestion.

Comment: Added a small paragraph about memory usage