# Swap partition is not working

Tags: partitioning, 17.10, ram, swap

My swap partition is not being used, I set the swappiness to 0 and fixed the UID in the config file to the UID of the swap partition but it's still at 0%.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? If you have a pretty high amount, the swap might not be used since swap is just RAM on disk space.

Comment: If your swap is empty, that is good. You don't want it to be used while the same task could still be done with RAM alone, because that would just slow everything down. Also, what Terrance said. Swappiness 0 means off.

Comment: @Terrance Correction: `vm.swappiness` means swap is only used when *absolutely* needed when set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

SWAP space is used for RAM paging in cases where you may run out of available memory.  If SWAP is active, but you are not using it, then it is likely that your resources are held in memory which has significantly faster read/write times than the SWAP space on a HDD.

To configre SWAP space, follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness) guide