# Ubuntu 16.04 use all swap instead of free memory

Tags: ram, swap

I have 128GB of memory but Ubuntu 16.04 seems to use all swap space instead of using 55GB free memory. So of course the load goes to the moon. Could someone help?

[image: htop]

Comment: See the answer to this question : https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness