# Is there any advantage/disadvantage to having far more memory than needed?

Tags: ram, memory-card

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on an Intel NUC 7i7BNH, with 16G of memory, which is far more than I would normally use (e.g. there's 12G free now).

I've just obtained another 16G card from retired hardware.

The question is, is there any advantage or disadvantage to installing that extra memory in my NUC?  Would it even ever get used?

Comment: Well, the biggest disadvantage is that it's not used and you've paid money for more RAM than necessary. What is good is that there's more room to catch a memory leak and notice it before your computer runs out of memory. But of course that's not a definitive answer, which is why it is posted as a comment

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantage might be it cost pennies a day in electricity but that seems trifle considering the cost of your IT department.

The advantage is Linux will keep programs accessed from disk once in RAM so they operate 100 times faster the second time.

Also as already mentioned you'll likely never be slowed down by swap file activity.

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to run without a swap file or swap partition, which is significant and meaningful. You don't need to dedicate space to either, and since that NUC only supports two drives (one 2.5" and one M.2), that's nice.

Also, running without swap means your system never has to drop everything and write to the drive. Even if you [set swappiness to 0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness), I have read of folks seeing swapping going on.