# No swapping on LUbuntu at enabled swap

Tags: lubuntu, ram, swap

I have tablet with 4 GiB of RAM and SSD 128 GiB with LUbuntu 18.04.

When the memory usage reaches approx. 3.9 G, the system hangs. Only the mouse pointer moves with lags. No reaction on Ctrl+Alt+Fx.

`swapon` is reported 8 GiB:

```
$ sudo swapon --show
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sda2 partition   8G   0B   -2
$ sudo sysctl vm.swappiness 
vm.swappiness = 60
$ uname -r
4.15.0-55-generic
```

Why the memory is not actually swapped? How to enable swap?

Comment: would you please add the output of `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness` to your question.

Comment: Thanks! The information has been added.

Comment: Please run `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10` and see how swap works afterwards. This will temporarily change the swappiness value until you reboot. If it works and you wish to make it permanent, please see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/103916/968501

Comment: @Raffa no, vm.swappiness=10 is the wrong way to go with 4G RAM. vm.swappiness=80 would be a better place to start.

Comment: @heynnema I see what you mean. Higher numbers tell the system to swap more. This is true. But sometimes when higher numbers do not work, smaller numbers do. I have no explanation for it, but that is what I observed. Plus the swappiness is already set to 60 which is high enough and I doubt an even higher number will make a difference

Comment: @Raffa I fixed one here just the other day with similar config and swap and symptoms, and 80 fixed the problem. We WANT the thing to swap before RAM is full and it freezes.

Comment: Even though you've changed your swap partition to a /swapfile, you still need to consider setting vm.swappiness=80 if you still have problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on personal experience, a swap file might be better utilized than a swap partition in newer versions of Ubuntu. You could try creating a swap file and disabling the swap partition and see how it works for you. To do so, please follow these steps:

1. Create the swap file ( 8 Gib ):

   ```
   sudo fallocate -l 8G /swapfile
   ```
2. Give the file right permissions to limit unneeded access:

   ```
   sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
   ```
3. Prepare the file as a swap area:

   ```
   sudo mkswap /swapfile
   ```
4. Activate the swap file:

   ```
   sudo swapon /swapfile
   ```
5. Deactivate the swap partition:

   ```
   sudo swapoff /dev/sda2
   ```

Test how your system swap behaves now.

---

**Notice:** ( except for the creation of the `/swapfile` ), these changes made to swap volumes are temporary and will be cleared after reboot. If you wish to make changes permanent,

- please edit your `/etc/fstab` file

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/fstab
  ```
- Add this line to the end of the file `/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0`

  example:

  ```
  /dev/sda2 none            swap    sw              0       0
  /swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
  ```
- Comment out the line with the swap partition ( */dev/sda2* ) by adding `#` before it

  example:

  ```
  # /dev/sda2 none            swap    sw              0       0
  /swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
  ```
- Save the changes by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

**`fallocate` or `dd`:**

Thank you to [@heynnema](https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema) for raising this concern in the comments section below:

> no, don't use `fallocate` to create /swapfile, use `dd`. Search for
> info about this here on AU.

I assume the concern is regarding the possibility of `fallocate` creating *file holes* which basically are portions of a file that contain null characters and are not stored in any data block on the disk. This in turn, if present, would render the swap file unusable.

To address this concern, let us have a look at the odds of `fallocate` creating file holes and the consequences of that.

It turns out:

- `fallocate` will not normally create holes unless it is operated on a preexisting file and the option `--punch-hole` is specified. Please read [Ubuntu Manpage - fallocate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/fallocate.1.html)
- `fallocate --length 8GiB swapfile` is suggested to create a swap file on Ubuntu man pages, please read [Ubuntu Manpage - mkswap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/mkswap.8.html)
- After all, if the created file contained holes in it, `sudo swapon` will throw an error `skipping - it appears to have holes.` and in this rare case which I haven't faced or heard of yet, the solution is simple. Just use `dd` to create the file in step # 1 above and move on. Do it as follows:

  ```
  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=8388608
  ```

  or as [@v_mil](https://askubuntu.com/users/109539/v-mil) did it:

  ```
  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1048576 count=8192
  ```

**In short, this concern is not worrying enough to give up on the speed gained by using `fallocate`.**

Comment: no, don't use `fallocate` to create /swapfile, use `dd`. Search for info about this here on AU.

Comment: @heynnema the `dd` method would be `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=8388608` but why? This is much slower than `fallocate` plus it makes no difference when it comes to swap areas.

Comment: If you check the other questions/answers here on AU that I mention, you'd see there IS a difference.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I did not try fallocate because on SSD `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1048576 count=8192` operates less than a minute. /etc/fstab has been edited imediatly after the steps above and checking the swap by `sudo swapon --show`  Now I will reboot using LiveCD for enlarging the OS partition to utilize the space of the swap partition.

Comment: @v_mil You are most welcome. Using `dd` with a high number of `bytes=1048576` is more or less the same as `fallocate`. Glad it helped.

Comment: @heynnema `fallocate` will not normally create holes unless it is operated on a preexisting file and the option `--punch-hole` is specified. Please read http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/fallocate.1.html. `fallocate --length 8GiB swapfile` is suggested to create a swap file on Ubuntu man pages, please read http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/mkswap.8.html . After all, if the created file contained holes in it, `sudo swapon` will throw an error `skipping - it appears to have holes.` ... In short this is not worrying enough to give up on `fallocate` speed. Thank you

Comment: I have done same steps but still swap usage is 0 !!! what should I do?