# Should I use an SSD as cache for Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: server, ssd, cache

I have an 128 GB SSD that I'm going to use as a boot drive on Ubuntu Server 18.04. The server will be mostly used as a media and file server.

I was wondering if I should use the remaining space on the SSD as cache or if that would even do anything.

Comment: I don't see why not, just [avoid using more than ~70% of the drive capacity](https://mashtips.com/maximize-performance-and-increase-life-of-ssd/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Should" is one of those judgmental kinda questions which end up with Opinions, which [we avoid here](http://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask). If, once you're used the system for a while, you feel you want it, there are SSD caching solutions like [Bcache](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2385795) ([more](http://linux.com/tutorials/using-bcache-soup-your-sata-drives)) as well as [general optimization methods](http://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization)  but really, the simplest thing to do is to add more RAM and adjust [swappiness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness).