# stata very slow to plot graphs in Ubuntu and others Debian based distro (elementary, debian)

Tags: 19.10, libpng, plot

For those who have tried to use stata under linux, probably already encountered some issues related to the icons and libpng12 library... while I could get those fixed and stata starts normally and display the icons, somehow, stata takes really long to plot a scatter plot with some 150.000 observations.

- I first thought it was a issue with stata, but it works fine under manjaro (arch-based, with gnome 3.34.1).
- I also tried multiple releases of stata (mp, se) and also multiple versions (14.2, 15, 15.1)... and the results are the same across all versions: works as expected in Manjaro and veeeery slow in Ubuntu.
- other than plotting, stata seems to run just as fast as in other systems.
- i first thought the issue was related to the **libpng12** library. I installed this library in several ways, including using the binary from arch repository, [from this ppa as in this tutorial](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/05/fix-libpng12-0-missing-in-ubuntu-1804.html) and
  also [manually from xenial's repo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download).
- also tried in elementaryOS (5.1) and ubuntu 16.04, so it is not a problem only with the 19.10 version.

**anyone has any idea what else I could try?**

edits (answering to questions)

- cpu: i5 5300U
- gpu: Intel HD Graphics 5500 (i think... definitely no dedicated chip)
- ram: 16gb
- comment: with the same computer, it works fine on windows... (on other computer, older one with i5 from 2nd gen, works fine on manjaro)
- if I `set graph off`, the creation of the plot is normal, but if try to export it to **png**, it takes really long time (export to **eps** is rather quick).
- while plotting, the **Xorg** process goes to 90~100% CPU usage (of 1 core). The same happens in **wayland** (but with XWayland process). Even if graph is not be displayed (window is hidden or when graph is set off and only being exported...)

  - it affects several versions of stata (14, 15.1, 16)

Comment: What GPU and CPU do you have?

Comment: thanks for asking! See edits above... I don't really think it is related to the specs, because it works fine on windows on same computer... and plotting works fine using R, for example... (of course, there could be some incompatibility issue with this model and the library used by stata... )... my latest guess is that the problem could be due to the libpng12 that I installed manually and its dependency (zlib, in ubuntu: zlib1g), that ubuntu has in its repo... maybe libpng12 expects another version of zlib... but I don't know i could "force" libpng12 to use another version of zlib... any idea?

Comment: shot in the dark but try to change the swapiness to 10 or so, see here https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness