# Ubuntu 20 freezes when swap nears limit, but there's free memory available

Tags: freeze, ram, swap

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo X1C 7th Gen with 16GB RAM. The swap is set to 2GiB.

Just after entering edit mode on a photo in Google Photos (in Firefox), which I'm pretty sure has a serious memory leak (because I've seen it increase memory consumption and slow down the system), the system froze like this:

[image: Hitting swap limit cauzed freeze]

It stayed like that for a good 3 minutes, with the mouse cursor barely dragging along (good luck taking a screenshot). Eventually it recovered. As you can see, there was plenty of RAM available.

What was going on, and how can I prevent this? `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` is the default, 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've [set swappiness to 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness#comment2005018_103916), I've never had this problem. Also, as Jons suggested, it makes sense to have much more swap, and I don't understand [why Linux Mint for example, creates a tiny 1GB swap file](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=339771) on a system with 16GB RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I've had something similar. Swap is generally expected to be between 1 and 2 times RAM so suggest you increase that. See https://linuxhint.com/change_swap_size_ubuntu/