# Game performance loss while using swapfile

Tags: games, performance, swap

Hello everyone and thanks for help in advance,

So, I recently added a swapfile (3GB) on my HDD with intention to increase gaming performance.
I configured it and got it ready for use.
My RAM is 4GB.

There is just one very strange thing happening, my FPS does increase from 40-45 to around 55-60, BUT the game keeps freezing constantly for short amounts of time.

So I am guessing it's due to "swapping" between RAM and swapfile memory, It might be some kind of delay or something.

Any help/advice would be great, thank you

Comment: Swap is no replacement for more-RAM.  Yes it can help (and helps heaps), but that help always includes the need to move RAM to swapfile & swapfile to RAM, ie. the addition of overhead is involved...  For some tasks improvement is good, for others it's minimal, for others the addition of more swap & more overhead reduces overall performance. You need to have the right balance, but in your case that is likely adding more RAM will achieve more (4GB isn't much, does your OS, desktop, & game libraries all match? or are you wasting ram by poor choices?)  We don't know your OS & release so can't help

Comment: @guiverc I am using Ubuntu 20.04, I just got to youtube and same freezing appears, so it's not just while gaming, it never happened before I made swap. If no solution pops-up I will most probably remove swap.

Comment: To get the best out of swap you need to match it with your applications & use-case. With boxes with 4GB of ram or less I'm always careful with RAM & app choice (ie. using apps that share libraries with other apps & desktop I use at the same time..)  For swap settings can be seen with https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq (*swappiness* may need config) or https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness

Comment: @guiverc Just to let you know that I've been through both links and I pretty much did the same myself earlier on, just experiemented with swappiness a little bit and rebooted my pc and now everything runs just perfect. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please write up what you did as the answer and post here (below as an answer, not in comment), include anything I said that was helpful (esp. links) or you worked out yourself!, and in time you'll be able to accept it as answer & gain some rep (inc. maybe even upvotes).  Well done!