# ubuntu lagging, ram not getting used

Tags: 16.04, ram

I've just installed ubuntu 16.04LTS and my laptop is taking too much time to start I have HP laptop, Intel coreI3 processor 4gb ram NVIDIA graphics card, and while opening 2-3 applications, it is lagging, is my RAM not getting used?

RAM may be not getting used, not sure
help me fix it, Thank you for your time

Comment: If you mean that swap is getting used a lot and RAM does not check already answered question on this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51785/swap-shoots-to-100-after-a-couple-of-hours-of-usage)

Comment: Please check the output of `free -h` when you're in a situation that makes you think your RAM is not used fully. [Edit] your question to paste it and we can help you to interpret the result.

Answer (score 1):

- To investigate the cause of the boot duration, please [create a boot chart](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/04/ubuntu-boot-chart-make-graph-with-your.html).
- For the slow graphics performance you should install Nvidia's proprietary graphics drivers from the [Additional Drivers application](/q/47506/175814).
- Your RAM is definitely being used. A lack of RAM may lead to performance issue but 4 GiB should be plenty. If you're still concerned look at the output of:

  ```
  LC_MESSAGES=C free -h
  ```

  The value in the line labelled “Mem” and the column labelled “free” should be quite low (< 1 GiB) if you have been using your computer for a few hours. If it isn't, that just means that your usage doesn't require that much memory.