# Ubuntu 17.10 grub and splash screen low resolution with Nvidia driver only

Tags: drivers, grub2, nvidia, xorg, display-resolution

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my PC. Then I installed the Nvidia driver in the additional drivers panel. Everything works fine except for grub and the splash screen. These two are in a very low resolution. But if I change back to xorg driver they work like they should in my dual monitor fullhd setup.

This seems a bit strange to me and even if I don't really need it it would be wonderful to have it working in fullhd with the Nvidia driver.

My system:
Ryzen 1600X @ 4.1 GHz
Msi GeForce gtx 1060 6gb

Comment: You might have success with this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/16899/512236)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit GRUB to set a custom resolution to fix this. If I remember correctly the splash screen will also be the correct resolution then.

Because editing the GRUB has potential consequences and terminals are scary I like to use a GUI for this.

Add the PPA and install Grub-Customizer

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Inside Grub Customizer, set the cutom resolution and save.
[image: grub customizer]

Comment: Well, that didn't quite work. I am on UEFI boot, is it possible that I therefore need an x24 after my resolution?

Comment: https://dreamerplays.github.io/InShot_20180312_011702965.mp4                   a video to the boot